# Flutter - Location setting does not show up in setting options [ Only iOS]

Tags: ios, flutter, geolocation, geolocator

I somewhat got in a tricky situation, I'm developing an app that highly depends on location services. It works perfectly fine on android but on ios, it says PermissionException permission is denied permanently.
I do have permission strings in my info.plist and I'm actively requesting it on the home screen if the permission status is not accepted in any kind. Besides that, I made a button that opens the app settings in settings.
There I cant find a location option at all.

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>some string</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>some string</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>some string</string>
```

Those are the permissions I'm using.

The version of Geolocator => geolocator: ^8.2.0

I kindly request help :) Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: i think i figured it out. Look here:
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/README.md

Make the changes to your podfile and add the macro permissions you need but read the readme file i linked above. Hit me up on skype if you need help: "nzein19"

Comment: Not sure if this is still an issue, however on iOS the `PermissionException permission is permanently denied` usually means the user denied permission once before. On iOS this means permissions should be granted through the iOS settings. Requesting permissions from your app will not suffice and iOS will not display the permission dialog. Instead go to "Settings" -> "Privacy" -> "Location Services" -> "Your App" and update permissions there.

Comment: @MauritsvanBeusekom I was also facing the same issue. Tried your suggestion, but under the location services, my app is not there.

Comment: Still I am not seeing Location Permission in App settings.